# How to use removeAtIndex if var parameter is deprecated

Tags: string, swift, deprecated

I am using a var for IPAddress, for which i wanted to remove trailing slash (/). Now i see a warning that `'var'` is deprecated. In such case how can i use `removeAtIndex` method in new style?

```
    if ipAddress.characters.last == "/" {
        ipAddress.removeAtIndex(ipAddress.endIndex.predecessor())
    }
```

Comment: I can see no `var` in your code. It would be helpful to provide a *self-contained* example exhibiting the problem.

Comment: you should provide a wider scope of your code, this one isn't enough to detect you var case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove var from the function parameter declaration and then create a mutable copy:

```
func myFunc(ipAddress: String) { // remove the var if you write here var ipAddress
    var ipAddress = ipAddress
    // change ipAddress here
}
```

`var` is only deprecated in function arguments.

See here the original change request:
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters.md

Comment: Doing so also giving warning. i wanted to know if var is removed, how do we use removeAtIndex ?

Comment: var is not deprecated. What is the warning?

Comment: i have used inside the function, warning is: var parameters are deprecated and will be removed in Swift 3. clicking on that warning,  showing me the line where i used var

Comment: You have to remove var from the function signature. Show your function.

Comment: similar func exist in another path, deleted that file. Now no warning for var ipAddress = ipAddress inside the func. Thank you